# How can I change the extension name in a string with bash?

Tags: bash

I want to translate the following python code to bash. The code changes the extension name to .html and runs Safari to open it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os.path
import os

oldName = $TM_FILEPATH
(name, ext) = os.path.splitext(oldName)
rename = name + ".html"
os.system("open -a Safari %s" % rename)
```

How can I change the file extension with bash?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
file=somefile.whatevs
open -a Safari "${file%.*}.html"
```

Comment: There's a good explanation over at [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1119299/347427): "When `%` is used in pattern `${variable%substring}` it will return content of variable with the shortest occurrence of substring deleted from back of variable."

Answer (score 10):

If you happen to know the extension you can switch it like this:

```
$ MY_FILE=file.html
$ NEW_EXT=${MY_FILE/html/php}
$ echo ${NEW_EXT}
file.php
```

Comment: what if its name my_html_file.html and I want to get my_html_file.php?

Comment: then you can write the substitution to match the dot indicating the extension `new_ext=${my_file/.html/.php}`

Comment: But careful if the search string occurs in the filename, here `my_html_file.html` willl be replaced with `my_php_file.php` and *NOT* `my_html_file.php`

Comment: `new_ext=${my_file/%html/php}` you need to match from the back.