# Running an SPTK command for all the files in a directory

Tags: bash, file, shell, command, repeat

I have the following command to convert a raw file into float

```
x2x +sf < /raw-en/1.raw > /raw-f/1.f
```

I need to run it for all the files in the directory "raw-en"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a typical use-case for a `for` loop:

```
for file in /raw-en/*; do
    x2x +sf < $file > /raw-f/$(basename $file .raw).f
done
```

**Edit:** Fixed output directory as noted by @ederollora.

**Edit[2]:** You should consider using `*.raw` in the `for`-loop to suite your use-case (thanks again to @ederollora).

Comment: But you should change *.raw to *, since he doesn't state just .raw files BUT ALL FILES in directory.

Comment: I actually just thought about this.  Thank you.  It's far too late… ;)

Comment: Aren't you allowed to change your answer?

Comment: brilliant, now that's a more than correct answer, fits the question perfectly. FOr the future, you could think of adding different cases if you think the person asking could have been mistaken or not asked all the necessary changes in the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the files in the directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in /raw-en/*; do
    x2x +sf < "$filename" > /raw-f/"${filename%.*}.f"
done
```

This should fit your case.

PD: Extension change taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4411117/2317111

Comment: Not exactly: All your output would go into `1.f`.

Comment: He doesn't tell where to go the ouput, he just tells he needs it to run for all the files in the directory, which, by the way, is not what you wrote. You should change it, or the person questioning should rewrite the question.

Comment: My scripts fits his requirements, but of course, he should rewrite his question in case the answer doesn't fit it.

Comment: Whoops, okay, you're right, I didn't notice the altered output directory.  And yes, I'd doubt he meant it this way, but strictly speaking you're assumption is technically fully valid.