# Bash equivalent of preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, bash, shell, sed

I have to remove the extension from a filename, and I was using this:

```
preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename)
```

I want to know what is the sed equivalent of this.
My current approach is this:

```
$(echo $filename | cut -f 1 -d '.')
```

but it does not work all the time.

and

Do regex and sed have same expressions for matching and the syntax is different or the expressions also change?

Comment: For regex in bash with sed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072592/replace-strings-using-sed-and-regex#14074855

Comment: Extract filename & extention http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash#965072

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the extension name in a string with bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411080/how-can-i-change-the-extension-name-in-a-string-with-bash)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples of cutting text with bash...

```
FileName="/var/www/html/index.html"
echo "${FileName}"
/var/www/html/index.html

echo "${FileName%/*}"
/var/www/html

echo "${FileName##*/}"
index.html

TmpVal=$(echo "${FileName%.*}")
echo "${TmpVal##*/}"
index
```

**Description...**

- **${variable%pattern}** removes first pattern on the right
- **${variable%%pattern}** removes last pattern on the right
- **${variable#pattern}** removes first pattern on the left
- **${variable##pattern}** removes last pattern on the left